# Automating the initialisation of multiple wsl instances

Tags: shell, terminal, automation, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I would like to make a shell script (or something similar) which fires up 6 separate wsl terminals, and then executes a specific program on each one. Each program is a server, so it cannot be all done from the same terminal, since they are non-terminating programs.

Is it possible?

Any help would be much appreciated!

K

EDIT: so now I am seeing that a file `newWsl.ps1` in powershell:

```
cmd.exe /c start wsl.exe --cd "~"
```

Then running:

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File .\newWsl.ps1
```

Is a start, however, there are very sparse docs now, it seems.

Ideally, something like:

```
cmd.exe /c start wsl.exe --cd "~" -run "script.sh"
```

Is what I need (where `script.sh` lives in the wsl home directory)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this.  You don't mention your distribution, so I'm going to assume Ubuntu since it is the default on WSL:

- *Option 1: Supervisord (or equivalent)*

  Normally, if you were starting six different servers in Linux, you'd want to do that through Systemd.  WSL doesn't easily support Systemd (due to Systemd's insistence on running as PID1).  However, we can easily use another process supervisor that doesn't require PID1.  `supervisord` is one I've used before on Ubuntu for this.

  ```
  sudo apt install supervisor supervisor-doc
  ```

  Create a file in `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/` for each of your servers.  For instance:

  `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/`:

  ```
  [program:program1]
  command=/home/youruser/program1.sh
  autostart=true
  redirect_stderr=true
  stdout_logfile=/home/youruser/program1.log
  directory=/home/youruser
  user=youruser
  ```

  Create one conf for each of your servers.

  Then, starting `sudo supervisord` will start all of your servers.  To do this when starting WSL:

  ```
  wsl -u root supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
  ```

  You can also then open another WSL instance and see them running with:

  ```
  ps -efH
  sudo supervisorctl status
  ```

  You can also see the captured output in each log file.

  See `man supervisorctl` and `man supervisor` for more information on configuring and controlling the servers.

---

- *Option 2: Tmux*

  If you need all of the output from the servers in the foreground, I'd recommend running the servers through Tmux, which is installed in Ubuntu on WSL by default.  Start multiple Tmux windows, each with a different application, via:

  ```
  wsl -e tmux new-session ~/program1.sh `; new-window ~/program2.sh `; new-window ~/program3.sh # and so on
  ```

  Then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd> (or 2, 3, etc.) to switch between them.  Personally, I always switch my prefix to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> for Tmux.  That's the `screen` (its predecessor) default, and it's much less of a finger-twister to reach.

---

- *Option 3: PowerShell `Start-Process`*

  Finally, what you probably think you are looking for (from the way your question is phrased) is `Start-Process` in PowerShell.  It's default behavior is to create a new process for each application.

  ```
  Start-Process wsl -ArgumentList "~ -e ./program1.sh"
  Start-Process wsl -ArgumentList "~ -e ./program2.sh"
  Start-Process wsl -ArgumentList "~ -e ./program3.sh"
  ```

  And perhaps it is.  While I'd prefer either the Supervisor or Tmux approaches, you may have a preference for multiple WSL terminals for your use-case.

Comment: Awesome! thanks! However when I use the commands, then window opens and immediately crashes. Am I missing something?

Comment: For which option?  On the first one, it will run and exit (since Supervisor runs in the background), and you can then open a new terminal to check whether the servers are running.  For the others, I'm not sure - I just re-tested, and they all still work for me.  For Supervisor, if the servers aren't running, you can check `/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log` or the corresponding `program1.log` file to see if there's a hint.

Comment: So for the option 3, this is how I am trying to run it: `Start-Process wsl -ArgumentList "~ -e ./program1.sh"`. For option 2, I tried to run: `wsl -e tmux new-session ~/program1.sh` Both exited as soon as I run the commands.

Comment: @AKRA Hmm - Do you scripts have shebang lines?  And I assume they are set `+x` permission, correct?

Comment: Also, I'm assuming that `wsl -e tmux` by itself works, correct?  Running without the `-e` may give you an error message with a hint.

Comment: So `Start-Process wsl -ArgumentList "~"` works fine, and so does `wsl -e tmux new-session`, but anything else is not working, even from console.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242934/discussion-between-notthedr01ds-and-akra).